# How to write bash script that will create a shortcut for a mac osx doc?

Tags: bash, macos, shortcut

I am completely new to bash scripting, and would like to know how I can *write a script to create a shortcut* to go on a *mac osx doc.*

This is to enable the user to open a specific file by clicking a shortcut on the mac osx doc.  In my case, the file in question is **.command** file that launches an application with the required arguments.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats easy, just dump the .command file into the terminal window and it will give you the path to the file, then

```
ln -s /Users/username/path/.command ~/Desktop/command
```

If you double click this the file will open. If you have not set .command to be opened by a given program just use " " and set the program you want it to be opened in.

Comment: It was a doc shortcut that I really wanted, but a desktop shortcut was really useful.  The method Larry Wall suggest worked well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, bash scripts do not work right out of the box. You can use shell script instead.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>**/Applications/Google Chrome.app**</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'

killall Dock
```

Make sure that you replace the string **/Applications/Google Chrome.app** with whatever application you want to put into Dock.

You can just open the terminal app and you can copy paste (with editing the name of the application you want to put into dock) and then killall Dock this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Vighnesh.  I tried the code and it did create a doc shortcut.  However, the shortcut has a question mark icon, and wouldn't open the file it was linking to.  Not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: Did you copy pasted the full absolute path of the application that you wanted to put onto the dock? Say for example the above script is only for the applications in /Applications folder. If your app is in some downloads folder then give that absolute path in the script. It should work.